Как в jquery отслеживатьки на динамические элементы
У меня есть скрипт который добавляет на страницу элемент, после того как на странице появился другой элемент.
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            mutation.addedNodes.forEach(addedNode => {
                try {
                    if (addedNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && addedNode.getAttribute("id").indexOf("thread-") !== -1) {
                        let icon = addedNode.querySelector("span.controls");
                        let threadUrl = addedNode.querySelector(".listBlock.main.PreviewTooltip").getAttribute("href");            
                        icon.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<a class="StarContent threadControl far fa-lock Tooltip loock" value="${threadUrl}"></a>`);
                    };
                } catch {return};
            });
        };
    };
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

Как мне отслеживать нажатие на кнопку
icon.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<a class="StarContent threadControl far fa-lock Tooltip loock" value="${threadUrl}"></a>`);

};
Этот способ не работает как я понял это из за того что при создании обработчика нету этих элементов
$(".loock").click(el => {
    console.log("123")
})


Что-то типо $(body).on("click", ".loock", ...) юзалось вроде.

Пробовал не обрабатывает

Должно работать)

-, еще раз попробовал, обрабатывает только элементы которые были до (подгружены не динамически )

Извини, я идиот, работает, спасибо большое
